# exporting phpmyadmin's queries in automated way in regular intervals

Tags: linux, database, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, cron

How can I export the queries of the phpmyadmin's database in an automated way to my local pc in the regular intervals.

Does cron help? can anyone help me with setting the crontab command? is there an alternative?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? You want to schedule SQL queries to the database and store the results? How are you currently executing a single query?

Comment: I have a program which is extracting raw data into the database. Then from that collected data, I want to run queries on them and save the resulted queries in my local computer. This task of executing the queries on the existing database and saving it to the computer has to be automated

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is an interactive tool for database administrators to use to manage a database; it's not designed to be automated. So no, there's no way to schedule phpMyAdmin to do the task you want.

That being said, there exist many tools (such as the MySQL command line client) that can run queries and may be able to help. Once you answer Lawrence's question about what you hope to accomplish, we may be able to guide you to an alternative solution.

Comment: I have a program which is extracting raw data into the database. Then from that collected data, I want to run queries on them and save the resulted queries in my local computer. This task of executing the queries on the existing database and saving it to the computer has to be automated

Comment: I got your point. I cannot automate the extraction of the query result from my database from phpmyadmin. Can you recommend some other tools in ubuntu which i can use to run the queries and keep saving the result in my computer